# Can't boot laptop at all after installing Mint 20 (GRUB messed up)

Tags: linux-mint, grub, live-usb, bios

I am, forgive me, a *total* newbie, but two days ago excitedly installed Mint Cinnamon 20 on a Medion Akoya E2215T laptop. I made several changes as per some tutorials, like decreasing the swappiness, etc., and customizing the desktop. Also beginning to learn about the command line.

The system froze several times and I had to do a hard reboot. It worked every time, until this last time I rebooted and got this message:

/boot/i1386-efi/normal.mod grub rescue

When I go into the BIOS, the option to boot from a flash drive has disappeared.

Please help! Thanks in advance, and remember I know next to nothing. Thanks.

Comment: I also have this problem of not seeing the stick in the BIOS from time to time. Usually the solution is trivial: Turning the system off, pulling the stick out and plugging it back in, preferably in another usb port, and checking the BIOS again after booting does it.

Comment: My problem is persistent, I've tried what you suggest, but no change.